# оповещение о покупке на емайл?

Tags: html, переменные

Требуется создать универсальный макет html письма для автоматических рассылок интернет-магазинов. Такое письмо будет приходить пользователю, который сделал заказ через корзину. 
На одной CMS работают несколько интернет-магазинов, имеющие, естественно, индивидуальный дизайн. Письмо будет универсальное для всех магазинов с программированием замены отдельных элементов. 
Вот как правильно вставить изменяемые элементы в письмо?

тоесть в письме отправляется "Здравствуйте, {name} [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: правельно :) )0

Comment: понимаю что тут использоваться должен php, но с ним дел не имела никогда, а сейчас нужно позарез(  
пример кода:

Comment: <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  valign="top"; height="100%" width="550"  align="center">
        <tr>
         <td width="160px" height="60px">
          <img src="ipg/barcode.png">
         </td>
         <td width="160px" height="60px">
          Здравствуйте, {name}
         </td>
         <td rowspan="2" width="120px">
          <img src="logo.php? id=asdfgh" width="120px" height="120px" />
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
         <td>
          
         </td>
        </tr>
        
       </table>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так, используя `str_replace`

```
$fileemail = file_get_contents('email.html');

$name="John";
$number=1312321;
$data = "12/01/17";
// добавляете в массив все  ваши варианты
$fileemail = str_replace(
array('{name}','{number}','{data}'),
array($name,$number,$data),
$fileemail);

echo $fileemail ;
```

Версия на сайте, рабочия

```
<?php
// присваивает <body text='black'>
$fileemail = file_get_contents('email.html');
$name="John";
$number=1312321;
$data = "12/01/17";
$art =1142;
$picture="./logo.jpg";
$Name_of_product ="Беговел РТ";
$quantity=2;
$price=2013;
$sum=2013;
$total=2013;


// добавляете в массив все  ваши варианты
$fileemail = str_replace(
array('{name}','{number}','{data}','{art}','{picture}','{Name of product}','{quantity}','{price}','{sum}','{total}'),
array($name,$number,$data,$art,$picture,$Name_of_product,$quantity,$price,$sum,$total),
$fileemail);
echo $fileemail ;
?>
```

Comment: подскажите а как тогда вывести эту переменную в теле письма
<td width="160px" height="60px">
<p> Здравствуйте,</p> .$name
</td>

Comment: если это html фаил , то он должен поддерживать php. используйте авто замену {name}. это работает в моем примере

Comment: ниже я вставила вырезку из самого письма, <?php .....?> не надо?
  вставляется в <head> <style>?
и строка вывода должна быть <td>Заказ успешно оформлен, {name}
         </td>

Comment: вы подгружаете html файл в php , делаете изменения над файлом , и отсылаете его. для этого нужен отдельный php скрипт, обработчик, который будет обрабатывать и отсылать email

Comment: ни чего не поняла( мне в html текст писать <a> Добрый день, logo.php? {name}.</a>   или просто <a>Добрый день, {name}.</a>

Comment: <a>Добрый день, {name}.</a>